# Javascript - Is it possible to put 2 values into 1 parameter of a function?

Tags: javascript, function

Example:

```
const exampleFunq = function (exampleParameter, exampleParameterTwo) {

}
```

Now when i invoke it, let's say i want to put 2 values into 2nd parameter;

`exampleFunq(1, 2 3)`

i know this code is wrong but is it a possible concept?

Comment: You can always pass an object or an array.

Comment: You can pass an array or an object.

Comment: What the other two people said, you would want to pass the second variable (exampleParameterTwo) as an array. So exampleFunq(1, [2, 3]). Unless you want 2 3 to be a string, you could pass exampleFunq(1, "2 3")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't have tuples as language concept, but you can always pass an [array](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp) or an [object](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp):

```js
function example (arg1, arg2) {
  console.log(arg1, arg2[0], arg2[1])
}

example(123, [456, 789])
```

```js
function example (arg1, arg2) {
  console.log(arg1, arg2.first, arg2.second)
}

example(123, { first: 456, second: 789 })
```

Using [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), you can make this seamless, if so desired:

```js
function example (arg1, [arg2A, arg2B]) {
  console.log(arg1, arg2A, arg2B)
}

example(123, [456, 789])
```

```js
function example (arg1, { first, second }) {
  console.log(arg1, first, second)
}

example(123, { first: 456, second: 789 })
```

Answer (score 0):

You could treat your 2nd (and 3rd, nth...) param as variable list of arguments.

```js
const exampleFunq = (exampleParameter, ...additionalExampleParameters) => {
  console.log([exampleParameter, ...additionalExampleParameters]);
}

exampleFunq(1, 2)
exampleFunq(1, 2, 3)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```